# Jade template code editor

Tags: javascript, editor, pug

Looking for convenient and fast jade http://jade-lang.com template code editor with highlighting and block folding. I know about Eclipse but it is not my choice. For Mac and for Windows will be great.

Comment: You might wanna try [softwarerecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Sublime Text 3. Download the package manager and then the Jade syntax plugin. It's an excellent editor. And I recommend Prepros for compiling as it will also compile Sass if you are using it.

I tried posting links to each resource but SO says it's unformatted code so. .